# New generation of chromecast device

Tags: chromecast

I have apps on App Store that were created for the first generation of chromecast.  Do they still work with the new just released generation of cast device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes they do, there is no difference between the two in terms of APIs or other aspects that would impact apps in a negtive way.